# Wrong to insert data in database using a insert function

Tags: php, mysql

function written is correct the query too. But the information is not saved in my database in table users.
This is the query when I print it.

```
INSERT INTO 'users' VALUE(NULL,'omardz','bankdz@gmail.com','3a9d086dcf50424fc60ccbc52173d49d','freelancer') 

include('config.php');
```

// the config file include user,pass,host,database, is connect without any problem!

```
function add_new_user($username,$email,$password,$type)
 {
  global $sbr_connect;
  if(empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($type))
    return false;

  $n_username = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($username),$sbr_connect);
  $n_email    = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($email),$sbr_connect);
  $n_password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($password),$sbr_connect));
  $n_type     = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($type),$sbr_connect);

  $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO 'users' VALUE(NULL,'%s','%s','%s','%s')",$n_username,$n_email,$n_password,$n_type);
  $qresult = mysql_query($query);

  echo $query;

  if(!$qresult)
    return false;

  return true;

  }


$resultt= add_new_user('omardz','bankdz@gmail.com','mououuu','man');
if($resultt) 
{
   echo 'success';
   sbr_db_close();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't show any errors at all?

Comment: Avoid mysql_ functions. These are unsafe and have been deprecated for a long time (and completely removed now iirc)

Comment: Also md5 is insecure as a password hash.

Comment: Please check your sql statement . you are putting VALUE instead of VALUES . please change to : INSERT INTO 'users' VALUES

Comment: the same @AzeezKallayi I try it many time

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: plus, what does this do `sbr_db_close()` that's not a core function

Comment: @AzeezKallayi `{VALUES | VALUE}` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html is valid syntax in MySQL.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for your valuable information

Answer (score 2):

This part of your query:

```
INSERT INTO 'users'
            ^     ^
```

you're using single quotes for your table which are not the correct [identifier qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

Either remove them `INSERT INTO users`

or use ticks

```
INSERT INTO `users`
```

`or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` would have signaled the syntax error.

---

Sidenote:

Consider using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

About password storage.

MD5 is old and considered broken.

Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

This `sbr_db_close();` is obviously a custom function and I have no idea what it does. So make sure that works.